# How to implement Facebook's `Drag Links/Photos Here`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I just noticed that if you drag anything on facebook, no matter it's a link, or image, or pure text, the `update status` part changes to a box saying `Drag Links/Photos Here`. I'm wondering how to implement this functionality? Or in other words, how to detect that the cursor is dragging and do any subsequent change of a particular element on the webpage?

Comment: there is a good tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp). it is new functionality for html5.

Comment: Can you break it down a little bit? Yes I can drag an element, but the box does not change. And I don't think facebook will make every single letter draggable.

Comment: Can you give us more details? Are you trying to upload files (or download if it's a link)?  There is more than one type of dragging action.

Comment: If you go to facebook, when you drag any content, no matter it's any text, or image or anything, the `update status` box changes to a droppable area, no matter whether the element you drag triggers any js function. So I wonder if there's any function that detects any drag action over the web page.

Comment: if you'd spend a little time examining the status box in the chrome debugger, you'd see that facebook has an entire library built around this functionality. if you want answers, i'd suggest you start digging into how they do it if you really want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps HTML5? The following links should help you understand how to implement drag and drop with html5. You might also want to check the second link which implements drag "anything".

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/

http://html5demos.com/drag-anything

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is in the drag function that Mike linked just add JavaScript to change what you want. something [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/) might help.

Comment: Now the problem is, if I make a `<p>` element draggable, I can only drag the whole paragraph. The regular text highlighting doesn't work any more. However it seems in facebook you can select any portion of the text and drag it. How to make this possible?